# Help regarding no sql databases like hadoop, hbase etc

Tags: database, memcached, nosql, hadoop, hbase

I am new to the distributed NoSQL databases like Hadoop, Cassandra, etc. I have few questions for which I seek an expert advice:

1. Can you list problems/challenges one will generally face when making a shift from the present conventional database like MySQL to these large cluster-based databases?
2. What are the difficulties, if any, when one needs to adapt to a newer version of these open source projects?
3. Can you list out the things which are generally stored/kept in memcached for fast rendering of the page?
4. How can I understand the source code of open-source projects so that I can build on it and maybe give back to the community?

Above questions may sound to be idiotic and basic but please it's a request for the experts to answer the above questions in detailed and to best of their abilities.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a few thoughts:

1: Documentation and examples have been a major challenge for my projects using Hadoop and related projects.  Compared to MySQL, it's often hard to find what features are available, and how to use them.  The mailing lists have been a great help in this regard.  Learning to think in terms of batch processing and 'full table scans' has also been an adjustment, and getting used to Map Reduce programming is non-trivial, although there are many tools available to shield you from writing raw map reduce.

2: Much of the Hadoop & friends code base is still basically alphaware, and sometimes things change a lot from version to version.  You'll definitely want a test cluster to do your upgrade on first and see what breaks.  Dramatic API changes are not unexpected during an upgrade.

3: I have not worked with memcached specifically, and I use Hadoop for back end ETL processing, not rendering pages.  Can't really help you here.

4: The best way to understand the projects is to get the code and start looking at it.  Practice using it for a while, and eventually you'll find something you think could be done better, or a feature you want.  That's as good a place as any to get involved.  Be sure to sign up for the developer mailing lists, and pay attention to the existing list of bugs and feature requests to see if someone is already working on something similar.  Most of these projects you'll need to get someone with commit rights to put your code in, but that isn't too hard.  Read up on the specific project you're interested in contributing to for more specific information.

Answer (score 0):

My experiences are:

1. The primary challenge would be to think in No-SQL terms when coming from relational background. For example, HBase (built on Hadoop DFS) will only give you ascending order, if you want to do a descending order lookup you will need to maintain a reverse index; i.e. ID 1 point to book A and in reverse index (max - 1) pointing to 1. Documentation is a problem but - the community, as in all OSS, is very important. Along Git and Jersey I would say the HBase community is extremely helpful so that makes up for the lack of documentation and HBase documentation is improving all the time. Another challenge would be searching. We often use SQL RDBMS for searching, HBase, e.g., is not at all suited for that purpose. It is advised to use other software for searching while using HBase for reliable storing, e.g. Elastic Search, Apache Solr, Apache Lucene etc.
2. That actually depends from project to project, in case of HBase There are improvements largely from 0.20.X to 0.90.X (its release is eminent). AFAIK the data store format does not change, neither the API drastically, but like any major OSS with major version change the API changes, but with minor changes there are no API changes. Though not vastly experience in upgrading, but from my little adventure in this I noticed not problem retrieving the data.
3. This is tricky and vastly depends on the type of application in question here. As you mention memcached I would like to share the experience we are currently going through. We are not using HBase for any searching other than straight forward primary key lookup. All other searches go through Apache Solr (which is based on Lucene). So search result is cached in by Solr. In application layer, as we use Java, we use Ehcache for storing raw objects. In the web caching we use [Varnish Cache](http://varnish-cache.org), using ESI we fragmented the page into per user content, e.g. login, logout, account, cart etc., and general content, e.g. news, events, products etc. the achieve high throughput.
4. I would like to agree with Mark Tozzi on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would revert back if any new doubt popups in my mind.Thank you once again